# How to play mp3 music on windows10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, mp3

Although this question sounds ridicouluous, I was not able to play a list of mp3 music on my new Windows 10 computer. Here is what I want to do:

Mark a list of mp3 files inside a directory, and have them all played back.

So, for example, I have 15 mp3 files inside a directory, I want to have them played back one at a time, automatically, without selecting a tracck after a track.

Is there a tool available for windows 10?

I tried for one hour and did not find a solution. Here is what I have tried:

- kodi, Plex: Did not work at all, one asked me to download a file myself, which was not there.
- MediaPortal: Not working
- MusicBeee: Probably codec missing
- 5kplayer: Works, BUT ONLY FOR ON GIVEN FILE AT A TIME. Unable to select a list of files...

So is there a solution to my problem? I do not require video playback, and I do not need an equalizer or some other stuff. Just to be able to PLAY A LIST OF MP3 MUSIC! Argh!

Comment: Windows 10 comes with Groove music which supports playlists.

Comment: No it does not!!! Default apps -> Music -> Nothing!!

Comment: How do you mean...? I'm using it with a playlist as we speak..?

Comment: My version of windows did not come with Groove. This is all I know. I have no Groove, and do not know where to download it from. WindowsApp does not work either for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a version of Windows 10 that is missing Windows Media components.  These are known as the "N" or "KN" editions and you can thank the European Commission for them.

From the [Windows 10 Editions page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-editions) there is a caveat at the bottom that states:

> “N” and “KN” editions of Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Pro are also available and include the same functionality as the standard editions, except that they do not include certain media related technologies (Windows Media Player, Camera, Music, Films & TV) and does not include the Skype app.

In order to add these technologies back into Windows you need to download the [Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231).

This will hopefully give you a nice simple media player that supports playlists and necessary codecs to support playback on other media players.

More information on the N and KN editions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#N_and_KN_Editions).

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days there was [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/) for playing mp3.

Comment: Is winamp still supported?

Comment: Try it. Else I would go for Spotify. See here on how to import mp3: https://support.spotify.com/de/learn-more/guides/#!/article/Listen-to-local-files

Comment: How to increase the menu font for winamp on windows 10? It is incredible small, I am almost not able to see the ""File", "Play", ... menu options!